# how can i run jhipster-registry in my external server with war file

Tags: jhipster

i have an application with one microservice and one gateway. I deploy my war(s) application in my external server

so how can i deploy jhipster-registry in my external server with war file

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question: what have you tried? what is the problem?

Comment: now i work with jhipster-registry in heroku,  but i want deploy the registry in my tomcat at my remote server, but when i deploy the registry war file to my tomcat ,nothing is displayed

Comment: No error in log file?

Comment: i add the logs in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

@Gaël Marziou

The log file of my  Registry

```
:: Running Spring Boot 1.3.6.
:: http://jhipster.github.io 
::-10-09 03:40:55.863  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.ApplicationWebXml  : The following profiles are active: dev
            2016-10-09 03:40:57.076  WARN 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definitio$
            2016-10-09 03:40:57.646 DEBUG 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.r.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Registering JVM gauges
            2016-10-09 03:40:57.672 DEBUG 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.r.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.427  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application configuration, using profile$
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.427 DEBUG 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Initializing Metrics registries
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.430 DEBUG 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering Metrics Filter
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.431 DEBUG 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering Metrics Servlet
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.431  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application fully configured
            2016-10-09 03:40:59.442  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistry   : Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.536  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor qu$
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.545  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 14$
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.623  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.625  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http ://admin:admin@lo$
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.747  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.748  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.748  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.748  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.989  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http ://admin:admin@localh$
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.997  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registri$
            2016-10-09 03:41:00.998  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
            2016-10-09 03:41:02.969  WARN 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configurat$
            2016-10-09 03:41:02.969  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sour$
            2016-10-09 03:41:02.977  WARN 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configurat$
            2016-10-09 03:41:02.977  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sour$
            2016-10-09 03:41:05.582  INFO 5278 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
            2016-10-09 03:41:05.583  INFO 5278 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
            2016-10-09 03:41:05.583  INFO 5278 --- [      Thread-13] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
            2016-10-09 03:41:05.660  INFO 5278 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.g.jhipster.registry.ApplicationWebXml  : Started ApplicationWebXml in 11.934 seconds $
            Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
            SEVERE: A child container failed during start
            java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHos$
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            ... 6 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.(WsServerContainer.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
        SEVERE: A child container failed during start
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHos$
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
        SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8004]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
        INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8762"]
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
        INFO: Stopping service Catalina
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
        INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8762"]
        2016-10-09 03:41:05.706  INFO 5278 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
        2016-10-09 03:41:05.725  INFO 5278 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shutting down ...
        2016-10-09 03:41:05.735  INFO 5278 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shut down
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
        SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [ReplicaAwareInstanceRegistry - RenewalThresholdUpdater] but has failed to$
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
        SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Eureka-JerseyClient-Conn-Cleaner2] but has failed to stop it. This is ver$
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
        SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [StatsMonitor-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create $
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
        SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Eureka-CacheFillTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to $
        Oct 09, 2016 3:41:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.  The eventual fol$
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1610)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.AbstractScmAccessor$1.run(AbstractScmAccessor.java:91)

        Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/util/FileUtils
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.support.AbstractScmAccessor$1.run(AbstractScmAccessor.java:91)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/util/FileUtils`: it seems your war file does not include jgit dependency required by JHipster registry as a Spring Cloud Config server.

Comment: By the way, it's a bad idea to use an answer to provide additional details to your question, you should just edit it.

Comment: ok thanks, i don't know that .
thanks so much for your response :))